# iron:router error when I try to fetch a client-side collection before everything else

Tags: meteor, iron-router

When I try to fetch a client-side collection(which is basically the language setting) before everything else loaded. But I'm getting an iron:router error.

Probably I'm making a silly mistake about the loading order of a Meteor App but I couldn't resolve the issue for two days.

In **client/lib/_translations.js**:

```
translations = {
    Visits: {
        en_US: "Visits",
        en_GB: "Visits",
        tr_TR: "Ziyaretler"
    },
    .
    .
    .
    "Language": {
        en_US: "Language",
        en_GB: "Language",
        tr_TR: "Dil"
    }
}

selectedLanguage = "en_US";
```

Which is OK. But when I try to pull from database:

```
selectedLanguage = settings.findOne().language;
```

It's giving me *"iron:router Organize your Meteor application."* error. Also I did not understand the reason why iron:router giving me this error.

What I'm trying to do is defining a global variable(`selectedLanguage`) before any client side code loaded.

You can get the whole project from [here](https://github.com/mertyildiran/Dermatron).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Earliest fetch can be achieved in the callback of `Meteor.subscribe()` like:

```
Meteor.subscribe('settings', function() {
    selectedLanguage = settings.findOne().language;
});
```